# Radius of Convergence of $ \sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \pi(n) z^{n}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I came across this question:

If $\pi(n)$ denote the Euler function. What's the radius of convergence of this power series? $$ \sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \pi(n) z^{n}$$

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: I never heard of $\pi(n)$ as "the Euler function". Is it the totient function or the prime-counting function?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Yes, is the prime-counting function.

Comment: Either way, the radius of convergence is $1$.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The radius of convergence is $1$ without knowing anything deep at all about prime counting. For $n\ge2$, we have $1\le\pi(n)\le n$. This gives the bounds, for $x\ge0$,
$$
\frac x{1-x}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty1x^n\le x+\sum_{n=2}^\infty\pi(n)x^n\le\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^n=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}
$$
and the series on both sides have radius of convergence $1$.

Answer (score 3):

The radius of convergence is one since by the Chebyshev theorem (the weak version of the PNT)
$$\frac{n}{\log n}\ll \pi(n)\ll\frac{n}{\log n}.$$

Comment: 1) Should the RHS and LHS of that inequality be identical? 2) can we say anything about convergence on the unit circle?

Comment: @Semiclassical: Yes, Vinogradov's notation here just means that for two suitable constants $c_1,c_2$, for any $n$ big enough we have $c_1\frac{n}{\log n}\leq \pi(n)\leq c_2\frac{n}{\log n}$.

Comment: We do not have convergence on the unit circle since the general term $\frac{n}{\log n}\, z^n$ is not converging to zero when $n\to +\infty$.